# How to efficiently multiply for every sub-array alone first dimension of a 3d np.array, Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a 3d np.array `x`, with `x.shape == (r, n, m)`.

This means alone the dimension `r`, each element is a 2d-array `n-by-m`.
For each of those 2d-array, I want to multiply it by an vector.

This is an example.

```
import bumpy as np
x = np.array([[[1, 2, 3, 4],
               [4, 5, 6, 7],
               [7, 8, 9, 10]],
              [[4, 5, 6, 7],
               [7, 8, 9, 10],
               [10, 11, 12, 13]],
              [[7, 8, 9, 10],
               [10, 11, 12, 13],
               [13, 14, 15, 16]]])
```

So `x.shape` is `(r=3, n=3, m=4)`. Alone the first dimension there are three 2d-arrays

```
r1 = [[1, 2, 3, 4],
      [4, 5, 6, 7],
      [7, 8, 9, 10]]

r2 = [[4, 5, 6, 7],
      [7, 8, 9, 10],
      [10, 11, 12, 13]]

r3 = [[7, 8, 9, 10],
      [10, 11, 12, 13],
      [13, 14, 15, 16]]]
```

For each 2d-array, I want to do the same operation: the first row is multiplied by `k**(n-1)`, the second row is multiplied by `k**(n-2)`, and so on. The last row is multiplied by `k**(n-n)`.

Take `r1` for example:

```
k = 0.9
n = 3
r1_operated = np.empty_like(r1)
r1_operated[0] = r1[0] * k**(n-1)  # n = 3, so (n-1) = 2
r1_operated[1] = r1[1] * k**(n-2)  # n = 3, so (n-2) = 1
r1_operated[1] = r1[2] * k**(n-n)  # n = 3, so (n-n) = 0
```

What I have written above is ugly, and can be very chunky if `r` and `n` are very large.

Do you know any elegant and efficient way to code this algorithm?

I am using Python3. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of [numpy.broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast.html):

```
x * (k ** np.arange(x.shape[1]-1, -1, -1))[:,None]
```

---

```
x * (k ** np.arange(x.shape[1]-1, -1, -1))[:,None]

#array([[[  0.81,   1.62,   2.43,   3.24],
#        [  3.6 ,   4.5 ,   5.4 ,   6.3 ],
#        [  7.  ,   8.  ,   9.  ,  10.  ]],

#       [[  3.24,   4.05,   4.86,   5.67],
#        [  6.3 ,   7.2 ,   8.1 ,   9.  ],
#        [ 10.  ,  11.  ,  12.  ,  13.  ]],

#       [[  5.67,   6.48,   7.29,   8.1 ],
#        [  9.  ,   9.9 ,  10.8 ,  11.7 ],
#        [ 13.  ,  14.  ,  15.  ,  16.  ]]])
```

For comparison:

```
def by_element(r):
    k = 0.9
    n = 3
    r1_operated = np.empty_like(r1, dtype=np.float)
    r1_operated[0] = r[0] * k**(n-1)  # n = 3, so (n-1) = 2
    r1_operated[1] = r[1] * k**(n-2)  # n = 3, so (n-2) = 1
    r1_operated[2] = r[2] * k**(n-n)
    return r1_operated

by_element(x[0])
#array([[  0.81,   1.62,   2.43,   3.24],
#       [  3.6 ,   4.5 ,   5.4 ,   6.3 ],
#       [  7.  ,   8.  ,   9.  ,  10.  ]])

by_element(x[1])
#array([[  3.24,   4.05,   4.86,   5.67],
#       [  6.3 ,   7.2 ,   8.1 ,   9.  ],
#       [ 10.  ,  11.  ,  12.  ,  13.  ]])

by_element(x[2])
#array([[  5.67,   6.48,   7.29,   8.1 ],
#       [  9.  ,   9.9 ,  10.8 ,  11.7 ],
#       [ 13.  ,  14.  ,  15.  ,  16.  ]])
```